# How to apply neo4j algortithms on sub graph?

Tags: graph, neo4j, cypher

I have a neo4j graph of article citations. Now I want to apply betweenness centrality to nodes in which article citation count (a property) is greater than `0`. I tried to apply on a complete graph but it is taking more time.

```
CALL algo.betweenness(
  'Article','cites', {direction:'in',write:true, writeProperty:'article_centrality'})
YIELD nodes, minCentrality, maxCentrality, sumCentrality, loadMillis, computeMillis, writeMillis;
```

I also tried query mode but unable to succeed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To only process `Article` nodes whose citation count is greater than 0, you could add an additional label, say `Cited`, to them. For example:

```
MATCH (a:Article)
WHERE a.citationCount > 0
SET a:Cited;
```

Then you could just change your existing query to use the `Cited` label in place of `Article`:

```
CALL algo.betweenness(
  'Cited','cites', {direction:'in',write:true, writeProperty:'article_centrality'})
YIELD nodes, minCentrality, maxCentrality, sumCentrality, loadMillis, computeMillis, writeMillis;
```